# MongoDB Query with multiple conditions and slice

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this Mongoose Query:

```
 return Domain.find({domain:req.params.domain})
 .where('date').equals(date)
 .exec(function (err, domain) {
    if (!err) {
      if (!isEmpty(domain[0].visitors)) {
        domain[0]['visitors'] = domain[0].visitors.slice(0,99);
      }
  }
```

I want to slice directly in the database and not after retrieving object. Mongoose cannot do this or it is not documented or I did not find documentation.

So I fall back to node.js native MongoDB Driver by using the collection keyword.

My code looks now as follow and fails:

```
return Domain.collection.find(

  { "domain":req.params.domain }, 
  { "date":date }, 
  { "visitors": { $slice:100 } }, 
    function(err,domain){
      if (!err) {
         res.status(200).send({
           domain:domain
         });
      }
```

**Full code**: https://gist.github.com/nottinhill/b3837d4c913b9e5dd879

I tried in MongoDB console to construct a query that will work, but cannot get this simple query to work. MongoDB documentation does not show how to query with two conditions. I want to:

**Pseudo-Code** of what I want:

```
find
   giveBack wholeDomainObject
   where domain == domain
   where date == date
   also slice visitorsArray
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Projection is a single object definition. Also you "query" for things rather than ask for matches in projections other than specific fields matching criteria. [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) is a special case that does not exclude other fields in the projection by default:

```js
Domain.collection.find(
  { "domain":req.params.domain, "date": date }, 
  { "visitors": { "$slice":100 } }, 
  function(err,domain){
     // process results here
  }
);
```

Probably also to note that the `$slice` here ( just like JavaScript ) is a defined "number of entries" and not a `n-1` reference as in an array index.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Now unfortunately I am seeing a "TypeErr: Converting ciruclar structure to JSON". Please note: inside the callback theres a res.status(200).send({domain:domain});

Comment: @SirBenBenji I have no idea what that means in the context of this question. It does seem a little "bizarre" though that your question was all about making a "slice" on the array in the returned document but your code suggests you don't even want to return that property at all. Perhaps you need to ask that in another question to make your point clearer to everyone who can possibly answer.